# Can I add my Wi-Fi credentials to ESP module remotely?

Tags: esp8266, esp32, iot, home-automation

I am working on Home automation project and I am stuck somewhere on connecting my smart switch board to internet through my home WIFI. Actually I want to connect my ESP module with my home Wi-Fi remotely.
I was think of something like creating a hotspot through my switch board and connecting the hotspot to my phone, after that I need to send my Wi-Fi credential through that hotspot from my phone to  to ESP. But I dont know actually how to implement it. I didn't find something similar like that so I came here.

If you guys have some different way or you know how to do it , then give me some information about it.

Comment: https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager